# Send google maps div on the back

Tags: css, google-maps

I have this situation

[image]

The popup comes out when trying to login. I would like it comes ON the google maps div

So, this is the style of my popup

```
.popup-inner {
    max-width:500px;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:9999999;
```

While the back becomes

```
.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

and this is the popup

```
    <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
            <div class="popup-inner">

                <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" method="post" class="form-signin">

                    <div class="form-group">
//content of the form...
                        </div>

                </form>
                <p>
                    <a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
                </p>
                <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

The map has is in a simple, while the pop

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

with this style

```
#map {
    width:100%;
    height: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: why don't you put `popup` div inside `map`?

Comment: because the popup comes in every page of the application, not only in this one with the map, so it is called by a Thymeleaf fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `z-index:2;` to `.popup`

```
.popup {
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some changes in your code, look at my snippet there are also some comments which you should read.

Hopefully this would do the job for you!

```css
.popup {
  /*display:none; //change it back to its original*/
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  top:0px; /* 0px is 0 by default cause there does not exist 0 pixels. So only 0 is ok */
  left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
    
.popup-inner {
  position:fixed; /* changed position: absolute to fixed */
  width:90%;
  max-width:500px;
  
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  
  padding:40px;
  
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border-radius:3px;
  background:red;
  z-index: 10;
}

    
    
#map {
  width:100%;
  height: 600px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: pink; /* used to check the positions, make sure to remove the line */
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
  <div class="popup-inner">

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" method="post" class="form-signin">

    <div class="form-group">
      //content of the form...
    </div>

    </form>
    <p>
      <a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
    </p>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>

  </div>

</div>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: with this settings, the popup is always on, and the background is always dark, and the popup remain under the map...

Comment: It is because the display: block; should be on display: none; and need to triggered by JQ or something. But I see you find the right answer (y)